# Brushes and rollers for polyurethane over exposed brick

Tags: painting, tools, polyurethane

I am looking for recommendations what type of brushes and rollers are best to apply two coats of oil-based polyurethane over this exposed brick wall. E.g. should I use a regular angled brush like I would with paint and as for the roller, should I use maybe a foam one to achieve a smoother surface?

Also, does thinner do anything to clean poly off brushes or is it pretty much trash after one coat so I should get cheaper brushes?

[image]

Comment: Sanity check: Why do you want to do this? Just to make it shiny?

Comment: to seal the mortar from dissipating

Comment: The cost of the brushes/rollers compared to the labour of cleaning and how lazy you are.

Comment: Do you believe the mortar will degrade in you lifetime?  If I really wanted to do this I would use water based poly in a matte sheene.